# How to print result of bubble sort function?

Tags: c, printing, bubble-sort

Bascially a beginner problem. I don't know how to output the result my function and to check whether the logic is correct. Any help would be great thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define SIZE 3
int sort(int numbers[]);//function prototype
int main (void){
    int response[SIZE];
    int count;
    for (count=0;count<SIZE;count++)
    {
        printf ("Enter your number %d\n",count);
        scanf ("%d",&response[count]);
    }
    printf ("The array when sorted is\n");  
    getch();
return 0;   
}
//function to sort array elements
int sort(int numbers[])
{
    int store;
    int x;
    for (x=0; x<=SIZE;x++)
    {
        if (numbers[x+1]<numbers[x])
        {
            store=numbers[x+1];
            numbers[x+1]=numbers[x];
            numbers[x]=store;   

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: for(int i=0; i < SIZE; i++) printf("%d", response[i]); sorry cause im on phone didnt try it

Comment: It's not sorting correctly. If it *did* sort correctly, you'd become *very* famous for finding an `O(n)` comparison-sort.

Comment: The first thing to do is to actually call the `sort` function in your `main`. Then just iterate over `responses` with a `for` loop printing each value in the array. But as has been pointed out, you'll find your sort isn't right. And even if it works it's not a bubble sort implementation.

Comment: thanks for your comments. i was hoping you could give an example of the code. i am using every way i know and i get it wrong. Thanks for letting me know the sort is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments your bubble sort implementation is wrong,
have a look in this link maybe it helps
[Bubble sort C - implementation](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-bubble-sort)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a moderately general purpose sort order check function (for arrays of integers):

```
void check_ascending_order(int n, int data[n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] > data[i+1])
            fprintf(stderr, "!! FAIL !! data[%d] = %d > data[%d] = %d\n",
                    i, data[i], i+1, data[i+1]);
    }
}
```

You'd invoke it with:

```
check_ascending_order(SIZE, numbers);
```

It will produce error messages if the data is not sorted in non-decreasing order (it allows adjacent entries to be equal).

If you don't have at least C99, you will need to modify the code slightly:

```
void check_ascending_order(int n, int data[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] > data[i+1])
            fprintf(stderr, "!! FAIL !! data[%d] = %d > data[%d] = %d\n",
                    i, data[i], i+1, data[i+1]);
    }
}
```

Note that this not producing a failure message only shows that one set of data was sorted, not that your sort function is correct for all possible inputs.

Another test you could/should do is conservation; make a copy of the original data set, and check that each entry in the original unsorted data also appears in the sorted output, just as often as in the original (so nothing went missing, and nothing magically appeared).

And printing the result can be done multiple ways.  One simple way is:

```
void print_array(int n, int data[n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("[%d] = %d\n", i, data[i]);
}
```

You can add tweaks like a tag string to identify the data, and specifying the file stream to write to:

```
void print_array(FILE *fp, const char *tag, int n, int data[n])
{
    fprintf(fp, "%s:\n", tag);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        fprintf(fp, "[%d] = %d\n", i, data[i]);
    fflush(fp);
}
```

You can then use:

```
print_array(stdout, "Unsorted", SIZE, numbers);
...code to sort the data...
print_array(stdout, "Sorted", SIZE, numbers);
check_ascending_order(SIZE, numbers);
```

Note that printing comes before the checking; it allows you to see the entire sorted result set first.  Also note that 3 entries to sort is tiny; you need to check on much larger sets, like 6, 7, 10, 100.